# Consolidate Parameter Sets to Python Functions While Maintaining Type Declarations

Tags: python, variadic-functions, dry, type-hinting, python-typing

I've searched around and can't seem to find anything really answering this type of problem or giving usable guidance on it.

I have several functions that take the same set of parameters, and I'm trying to reduce the number of parameters that must be manually defined in each function so that I can focus on defining and handling the parameters that are unique to the given function. All this while maintaining typing and other helpful information for callers. I understand if I just have to suck it up and write out a bunch of parameters for each one, but it feels dirty and like there must be a better way of approaching this problem.

As a "practical" example, I've got something like the following:

```py
from typing import Any, Optional

def get_a_objects(name: str, limit: int, ... other common params to all objects ..., a_specific_param1: Any, ... params specific to A objects ..., limit: int, offset:int, create_ts: datetime, ... other common params to all list/get endpoints ...):
   pass

def get_a_object(id: int):
   pass

def set_a_objects(id: int, name: Optional[str] = None, ... other common params to all objects ..., a_specific_param1: Any, ... params specific to A objects ...):
   pass

def get_b_objects(name: str, limit: int, ... other common params to all objects ..., a_specific_param1: Any, ... params specific to B objects ..., limit: int, offset:int, create_ts: datetime, ... other common params to all list/get endpoints ...):
   pass

def get_b_object(id: int):
   pass

def set_b_objects(name: str, limit: int, ... other common params to all objects ..., b_specific_param1: Any, ... params specific to B objects ...):
   pass
...
```

Where the number of common parameters is large, and the number of object specific params is large, and the number of common get/list parameters is large as well. What I've thought of doing is something similar to

```py
def a_get_params(f):
   def wrapped(*args, ... params specific to A objects ..., **kwargs):
       return f(*args, **{**dict(params specific to A objects), **kwargs})
   return wrapped
```

Where I would then decorate all "A" specific functions with this decorator for example, and could do similar for "B" specific functions, or for "list" specific functions and just stack decorators as needed.

Though this also feels needlessly complicated. Plus calling `help(get_a_objects)` once it's decorated I don't believe will actually show any of the A-specific parameters nor their types, which kinda ruins the point of putting typing information anyways?

Has anyone come across a way to overcome this without just typing out 30 parameters for every single function definition/call, particularly when most of them are optional ones? Plus then I get linters yelling at me for having functions with too many parameters... which is fine to ignore at times, but when it's all of the functions, it makes me definitely feel like I'm doing something wrong here and there's gotta be a better way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't collect the common parameters into a single object, such as a `dict`, `namedtuple`, `UserDict`, dataclass, etc?

Comment: @Brian maybe? I'm not sure, could you give an example of such? For what it's worth, if I were to make a bunch of class/objects and pass those around, I would still need to decompose/serialize them into JSON as this is part of a JSON-based HTTP API Client.
Using dictionaries to pass them around, I think I would lose the typing information, and I would have a harder time caching any of the requests using functools.lru_cache for example.

Comment: I have exactly this problem - did you find a solution?

Comment: I ended up with several Classes for (in my example) A objects, (and for B objects, etc.) that would have .push and .pull methods on them that could be used to update the objects locally or push any changes I made on my local end to the API upstream. For searching for many of A objects (in my example, get_a_objects function), I had a function (outside of the class) that would perform the lookup. This ended up taking an exemplar A object along with other params (such as offset, limit, etc.) that could encompass the properties of A objects I wanted to search for, which was sufficient for my case.